# Android Eclipse how create link addresses

Tags: android, eclipse, hyperlink, createfile

Hi i have a big problem,

How i can create a link? For my Andoird APP no HTML! Java !!

I have a vb.net Code its this funktion what i need:

```
label3.text = label1.text + Textbox1.text + label2.text
```

People insert a number to the edit text then press the People a button then Create a link whit the "html://"+ edittext + ".html" that is all what i need.

e.g.  `"httml://"  +edittext + ".html"`

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean display a link in TextView so people can click it?

Comment: No People insert a number to the edit text then press the People a button then Create a link whit the "html"+ edittext + ".html" that is all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        url.setText("http://" + input.getText().toString() + ".html");
    }
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you very much
I would kiss her for the code is doing very well!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're working with Cordova. You could use `<a href="#">link</a>`, but it all depends on which framework you're working(eg. native JS: location.href, jQuery: changePage(), etc.).

Comment: You have probably not understood my question. I know how to link in a html link.  I need to create a link in java!

Comment: Ok, it was indeed not clear to me. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html for info about creating a link in JAVA. eg. `URL myURL = new URL("http://example.com/pages/");`